# Set Selection throughout all sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with multiple sheets. I want them all to scroll in sync. For example if I scroll to `J18` in Sheet1, all others sheets will have the cursor at `J18` and same row/column at the top left.

I know how to write (basic) scripts - but could not figure this one out. Any ideas?

<sup>Question on Google+ community: https://plus.google.com/113862354064807861446/posts/D7b919WFFjY</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing you can have is the following script.

### Code

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Harmonize")
    .addItem("Go !!", "mySheets").addToUi();
}

function mySheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // retrieve number of sheets
  var nshs = ss.getNumSheets();

  // find first sheet
  for(var i=0; i<nshs; i++) {
    var sh = ss.getSheets()[i];
    if(sh.getIndex() == 1) {
      var aCell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
      var index = i;
    }
  }

  // set active range throughout the sheets
  for(var j=0; j<nshs; j++) {
    if(ss.getSheets()[j].getIndex() != 1) {
      ss.getSheets()[j].setActiveSelection(aCell).activate();
      Utilities.sleep(200);
    }
  }

  // return to first sheet
  ss.getSheets()[index].setActiveSelection(aCell).activate();   
}
```

### Explained

Upon opening, a menu item is created. Selecting this item, will execute the `mySheet` function. This will find the first sheet (doesn't need to be `getSheets[0]`) and its `index` plus the `A1Notation()`. After that, it will set the active selection of each sheet according to the first sheet.

### Example

I've created an example sheet for you:  **[Set Selection throughout all sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hEzcBVjcHa9a_Iz21n7GsWpbQqrJG2nosq8Eg7R_bGo/edit?usp=sharing)**